# How to connect to MySQL database from another PC online? VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, networking, visual-studio-2013, mysql-workbench

Here is my connection string

```
mySqlCon.ConnectionString = "server=testserver.noip.me; port=3306; database=testserver1; uid=admin; pwd=admin"
```

I have created a vb.net application with *TryCatch* function to check MySql connection.

My **server** `testserver.noip.me` is a hostname of my **public ip** **(The hostname is an example, if you check the port online, it wont work)**. If I change the server to **localhost/127.0.0.1** or my **private ip** address which is something like **192.168.0.xx**, the result is connected just fine. Able to connect to database even on another PC but within the same wifi network.

Whenever I change it to my public ip address or my hostname, the application returns an error message :

> "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Here is the code

```
Try
        mySqlCon.Open()

        If mySqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Label5.Text = "Online"
            Label5.ForeColor = Color.GreenYellow
            LoginBtn.Enabled = True
        Else
            Label5.Text = "Offline"
            Label5.ForeColor = Color.LightPink
            LoginBtn.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If

        mySqlCon.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        If mySqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            mySqlCon.Close()
        End If
Finally
        mySqlCon.Dispose()
    End Try
```

*I have also done port forward in my router and the result is fine :*
[image]

*And the hostname port 3306 check is open as well:*
[image]

*Extra info : I have installed connectornet and is using MySQL workbench for this.*
[image]

Everything is working fine on local network but not online. Any idea what I should do to make the application connect to the database successfully from another network online? No SSH or any secure connection guide please because this is just a test server.

Comment: Are you able to access database via MySQL Interface (If installed any) on the remote PC, where you want to get it connected?

Also you can try Servername/Instance

 e.g. testserver.noip.me/myInstance

Comment: @SJSSoft No, i did not install the interface on the remote PC.. I just send the publish files, installed the vb application from setup.exe (which automatically download the connector as well)

Comment: Then you must test connection string using Instance. I had same problem. I have ip 172.XX.XX.XX and when I tried to access it locally, it was working, but on remote it failed. Then I used 172.XX.XX.XX/rserver, it worked.

Also try IP instead of Server Name.

Comment: @SJSSoft I tried using my public IP for the server but failed as well. Btw, how do I test it using Instance?

Comment: Download Workbench (MySQL GUI) from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ and Install It. Then Try to Access Remote DB using Workbench.

Step By Step Guide to Connect a Remote DB using WorkBench https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-server-connections.html

Comment: @SJSSoft Even if it works, I dont want to connect to another PC database and share the same parameters in both PC. I just want the vb.net application from the remote PC to connect to my PC(which where the database is)

Comment: It is just to test, whether database is accessible on remote system or not. If not, then what will be the right connection string.

Answer (score 0):

In your MYSQL (source machine) you have to enable the destination domain name for access rights.
In the host table add your destination IP.

Comment: How do I enable the destination domain name? Do you have any example?

Comment: Usually this option will be available in the username and password creation part.
I am using phpMyadmin interface to access mysql. It has the option to enable a specific host to use mysql.
Also  ensure that the firewall in the remote computer does not affect your mysql driver to communicate with other domain.

Comment: You mean you can sync myphpadmin database to mysql workbench?

Answer (score -1):

It's Because You Did Not Forward Port.

Go to Your Router Settings, Find Port Forwarding Add A Service With HTTP, Enter Your Local IP Address, Then Specify 3306 Port As Ending Port.

This Worked For Me. Perhaps It Will For You Too.