# How to access to MySQL database online?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, networking, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I know this kind of question has been repeating so many times but there are no proper answer for it.

As a summary, I have tried connecting to localhost and my private ip address and it works fine. I have also port forwarded the port 3306 in my router, tested the external ip port (which is successfully opened).

The connection wont work if I use my **public** ip address for the 'server' connection string.

Link below provides more detail on my issue D: Today is the 4th day I am finding a solution to this.

[Similar Question Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739561/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-from-another-pc-online-vb-net/31741905#31741905)

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think its a network issue (if you configured port forwarding properly)
I've had similar issue connecting to the server from the wan (or the lan) and I fixed it that way:

1. my server was running on Linux, by default the configuration of the server permit connection only from localhost, so to fix that I've edited /etc/mysql/ my.cnf file:   changed the bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0
   (if the version is kind of old you have to comment the "skip-networking" command).
2. also (very important) i gave privilege to connect the specific database that the application need to connect,  via PHPmyadmin >> choose database >> use privileges tab.

That is the code that i`m using to connect, it works perfect from the wan (via external ip) and also from the lan to the remote server.

hope it helps...

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    Dim myConnectionString As String

    myConnectionString = "server=XX.XX.XX.XX;" _
                & "uid=root;" _
                & "pwd=435435;" _
                & "database=Test;"

    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
        conn.Open()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT name FROM Test_Table"


        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        ' cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Usernametextbox.Text)
        Dim userLevel As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        MsgBox(userLevel)
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: The server is the public ip address right? Just to confirm it is NOT the private ip?

Comment: Extra : I am using mysql workbench. The latest version. And there is no bind address. They have removed it from this version I guess

Comment: yes, the "server" in the code assigned the public ip (the router will port forward it to the servers private ip...). this are the commands in the my.cnf file on my Linux machine:                                                                   #Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
    # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
    bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

Comment: I think that might be the problem of my issue. But there are no my.cnf file on my Windows MySQL :(